# Application of Chebyschev inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, rearrangement-inequality

[image]

I want to prove the inequality above.  On the extreme ends we get a clear application of AM-GM, and I want to use the chebyschev inequality for the middle but was having trouble.

**My Attempt:**

Since Chebyschevs inequalty is
[image]

We can square the left hand side of our inequality with the term to its right to get

$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\cdot \frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq \frac{ca+b^2+ca}{3}$$

**My problem**

I would've wanted to get $\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{3}$ on the right instead.  Did I apply the inequality wrong, or does it follow that $\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{3}$ is less than or equal to $\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}\cdot \dfrac{a+b+c}{3}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your inequality is wrong.

Try $a=1$, $b=-1$ and $c=0$.

For non-negatives $a$, $b$ and $c$ we see that $(a,b,c)$ and $(a,b,c)$ they are the same ordered.

This, by Chebyshov we obtain:
$$3(a\cdot a+b\cdot b+c\cdot c)\geq(a+b+c)(a+b+c)$$or
$$3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq(a+b+c)^2$$ or
$$3(a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc))\geq(a+b+c)^2+2(ab+ac+bc)$$ or
$$(a+b+c)^2\geq3(ab+ac+bc)$$ or
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq\sqrt{\frac{ab+ac+bc}{3}}.$$
By the same way we obtain:
$$3(ab\cdot ab+ac\cdot ac+bc\cdot bc)\geq (ab+ac+bc)(ab+ac+bc)$$ or
$$3(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)\geq(ab+ac+bc)^2$$ or
$$(ab+ac+bc)^2\geq3abc(a+b+c).$$
Now, $(ab,ac,bc)$ and $(c,b,a)$ they are opposite ordered.

Thus, by Chebyshov again we obtain:
$$(ab+ac+bc)^3\geq3abc(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)=3abc(c+b+a)(ab+ac+bc)\geq$$
$$\geq3abc\cdot3(c\cdot ab+b\cdot ac+a\cdot bc)=27a^2b^2c^2,$$
which gives
$$\sqrt{\frac{ab+ac+bc}{3}}\geq\sqrt[3]{abc}.$$

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted here the use of the Chebyshev's Inequality doesn't help much. However we can make use of the AM-GM inequality.

Squaring both sides and expanding them we get that the inequality is equivalent to: $(a+b+c)^2 \ge 3(ab+bc+ca)$, which is equivalent to $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + bc + ca$.

The last equality is true, as we have that $a^2 + b^2 \ge 2ab$, $b^2 + c^2 \ge 2bc$ and $c^2 + a^2 \ge 2ac$. Add the inequalities to get the final answer.